# Scroll to id within a division in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select object:

```
<select class="groups" id="groups">
    <option value="index_birmingham">Birmingham</option>
    ...
    <option value="index_wyboston">Wyboston</option>
</select>
```

I have division which contains several header objects, each having an id that corresponds to value in the select:

```
<div id="previewer">
    <h3 id="index_birmingham">Birmingham</h3>
    ...
    <h3 id="index_wyboston">Wyboston</h3>
</div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(".groups").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
        scrollToDivision(value);
    })
);
function scrollToDivision (value) {
    $("#previewer").animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + value).position().top }, 'slow');
}
```

However, while this functions perfectly for the first selection from the select, it fails for every selection after that; it's jumping up and down with apparent randomness.

I'm guessing there's some kind of position pointer which needs clearing so that jQuery knows where to jump to next, but after a few days of searching, I can't find anything.

I've tried the [ScrollTo by Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), but it doesn't appear to support select objects.

[Here is an example of the weirdness](http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/B3JXA/1/) I'm experiencing.

Comment: As an aside, `$(this).val()` or `this.value` will give you the value of the selected item in the select element, you don't need `$(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")`.

Comment: Is this problem on a specific browser? This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/MxuC6/

Comment: @KevinBowersox - That seems to work because it only includes two options so it's only ever scrolling to the top or the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"while this functions perfectly"*

Or it would if you actually passed a function to `.ready()` - you current pass the return value from `$('.groups').change()` (presumably an empty jQuery object at that point) to `.ready()`. But assuming that's just a copy/paste error...

The `.position()` method returns "the current position of an element relative to the offset parent". After you've already made a selection and scrolled the containing div the current position of the h3 elements will have changed and, e.g., if you scroll to the bottom one the top ones will likely have a negative vertical position because they've disappeared off the top. You can see exactly what value `$('#' + value).position().top` returns with the help of a `console.log()` statement as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4pKC/).

You need to take the current scroll position into account. Or just note the initial positions of all the headings:

```
var positions = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = $("#previewer").position().top;
    $("#previewer h3").each(function() {
        positions[this.id] = $(this).position().top - offset;
    });
    $(".groups").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        scrollToDivision(value);
    })
});
function scrollToDivision (value) {
    $("#previewer").animate({ scrollTop: positions[value] }, 'slow');
}
```

Demo (tested in Chrome only): http://jsfiddle.net/Q4pKC/1/

You didn't show your CSS or say so explicitly, but I'm assuming your previewer div has `overflow:scroll`?

**UPDATE:** Same JS as above, but with the OP's markup and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/B3JXA/2/

Comment: I'm using overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll. So far, this is the closest to something that functions consistently, although the positioning is out by about 3cm each time; perhaps it's a padding / margin thing?

Comment: I suspect it is a padding/margin thing that you could adjust for. As I noted in my answer I only tested it in Chrome, but for me the headings line up perfectly to the top of the previewer div (testing both with the markup/css I guessed at before you provided a demo and with the markup/css from your demo). EDIT: I just tried FF and it worked fine too.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome (though I'll expand to different browsers at a later date), and so far it's out by 250px positions[this.id] = $(this).position().top-(offset-250);

Comment: Even on the demo on the last line of my answer?

Comment: No, this is here, at this end. Your example is spot on, so I clearly have issues here. Thankfully, it's consistently out by 250px for every selection, which means if there's any variation between the browsers, I only need switch for a number.

Comment: After running the application through Chrome on Windows (I'm on a Mac), along with Safari, and Internet Explorer, they're all slightly out, but by varying amounts, whereas on the Mac, Chrome and Safari are more or less in agreement. Anyway, you've solved the core problem, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your solution is

```
$("#previewer").animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + value).position().top }, 'slow');
```

You are trying to animate `#previewer`, you have to animate `html, body` rest is alright.
Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/IRIyOpEb/2/edit) for better understanding.

**UPDATE:**
Since you needed to scroll the priewer div only you have to provide some fixed height to it with `overflow : auto`.
**Updated fiddle** [here](http://jsbin.com/IRIyOpEb/2/edit)

Comment: As I said in an earlier message, $("html,body") is scrolling the whole document and not the division.

Comment: @WayneSmallman I have updated the post to scroll only the division. And your fiddle works fine in my browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. However, @nnnnnn is closest to something that works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked quite well :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $previewer = $('#previewer'),
        previewerOffsetTop = $previewer.offset().top;

    $('#groups').change(scrollToDivision);

    function scrollToDivision() {
        // this (groups select) .value gets the value of the option selected
        var $division = $('#'+this.value),
            top = $division.offset().top - previewerOffsetTop;

        $previewer.animate( { scrollTop: top }, 'slow' );
    }
});
```

Edit: i made a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B3JXA/

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Again, it's finding the first id, but then jumps around randomly after that, only occasionally hitting the location of a header.

Comment: Try this and you'll see what's happening ( http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/B3JXA/1/ ).

Answer (score 0):

I think `Jquery` is **not needed**, it can be simply achieved by using the `anchor` tag.

```
<select class="groups" id="groups">
<option value="index_birmingham"><a href="#index_birmingham">Birmingham</a></option>
...
<option value="index_wyboston"><a href="#index_wyboston">Wyboston</a></option>
```

I think it might be helpful..

Comment: But (a) that won't animate, and (b) you're not really supposed to put anchors inside option elements. (And (c) Will that work when the elements in question are inside a div that has `overflow:scroll`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn ok buddy, Why shouldn't I put anchor within the option, could you clarify it?

Comment: I have something similar to this elsewhere in the application, which does work, but it is a little clunky and could be replaced with ScrollTo (eventually).

Comment: Well the [html spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-option-element.html#the-option-element) indicates that option elements should only contain text - is that clarification enough? In practice I can't say what _all_ browsers do with markup like what you've shown, but I think you'll find Chrome, FF and IE will all ignore your anchor tags and just keep the text content... (Feel free to provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net to prove me wrong.)